# Videos won't play on FB

Tags: flash, adobe, video-player, facebook

This after recent update. Was missing Youtube videos as well but that repaired itself when I refreshed FF. Was suggested by Adobe to make flash my preferred/ default player but I don't know where those settings are stored to do that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to reboot if you haven't already. If that doesn't help, can you please provide a URL to a video which doesn't play for you.

Comment: @Gunnar ...https://www.facebook.com/1556242517735342/videos/1740701189289473/  This is just one, others are white screen as well, but there is some audio. "Your video failed to play. Learn more" prompt leads to: https://www.facebook.com/help/www/396404120401278?rdrhc

Comment: I can view that video fine. Which Ubuntu version do you have? Affected by [bug #1643467](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1643467)? Btw, is [adobe-flashplugin](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) installed?

Comment: @Gunnar ...12.04, I would upgrade if I knew a trusted source. I don't know if that plugin is installed, how can I find out and do it if it is not?

Comment: @Gunnar ...Thank you I visited the bug page and installed those fixes and rebooted, it works for now. Hopefully new updates won't overwrite it? Thanks again.